# How to display different values in same column into single Row in SQL server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I had a below two table which has

```
 ID      TextID     Description
 -------------------------------
 1        2          zzzz
 1        3          kkkk
 1        4          llll
 5        2          nnnn

 TextID      TextTypeID     
 -------------------------------
 1            R1
 2            R2
 3            R3
 4            R4
```

I want result for the ID like below using Case statement.Please advice.

```
 ID      R1      R2    R3     R4
 ---------------------------------
  1      null   zzzz   kkkk  llll
```

Comment: Either use of a pivot statement or case.  without using Dynamic SQL you will have to know all the available column names.  If the column names are variable, then you'll have to use dynamic SQL.  Asked and answered alot on this site: here's one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617713/how-to-create-a-pivottable-in-transact-sql  and another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824475/row-convert-to-column-in-sql-2008

Comment: Do you know how many columns you are going to have, or is there a limited number of data specified in TextTypeID?

Comment: there is limited number of TextTypeID

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making row values into column values -- SQL PIVOT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9117955/making-row-values-into-column-values-sql-pivot)

Answer (score 0):

I named the tables #a, #b, and #c sense you did not provide names.

```
create table #c
(ID int not null primary key)

insert into #c (ID)
select distinct ID
from #a

declare @TextTypeID char(2)
declare @sql varchar(max)

declare r_cursor cursor for
select distinct TextTypeID
from #b
order by TextTypeID

open r_cursor
fetch next from r_cursor into @TextTypeID

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    set @sql = 'alter table #c add [' + @TextTypeID + '] char(4)'
    exec (@sql)

    set @sql = 'update c set [' + @TextTypeID + '] = a.[Description]
    from #c c
    join #a a on c.ID = a.ID
    join #b b on a.TextID = b.TextID
    where b.TextTypeID = '''+ @TextTypeID + ''''
    exec (@sql)

    fetch next from r_cursor into @TextTypeID
END

close r_cursor
deallocate r_cursor

select *
from #c
```